# How to pass in multiple complex query in mongoose using express where the schema's are embedded to render it my ejs file

Tags: express, mongoose, controller, schema, ejs

```
//GET /teams/:id/players/:playerId     --> single team --> getting single player
module.exports.getPlayer = (req, res, next) => {
    TeamModel.findOne({ _id: req.params.id }, (err, result) => {
        console.log('Result: ' + result.players);
        // let player = _.where(result.players, { id: req.params.playerId })
        res.render('playerDetails', {
            title: 'Player Details',
            playerDetails: result
        })
    })
};
```

Since req.params.id yields me the id before the /player/:playerId
I want something that will help me get both the id and eventually end up with :playerId

which I want to pass down my 'playerDetails' file.

```
<td>
<%=playerDetails.players[1].playerName%>
</td>
```

the code that I have in my ejs file is above, which is a hardcoded value to yield out a player name.

But I just don't know how to pass the specific :playerId from my getPlayer controller, where I won't have to hardcode the value to list out the player name in my ejs file.

What should I do? 
Thanks.

Comment: Never mind solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My controller function :

```
//GET /teams/:id/players/:playerId     --> single team --> getting single player
module.exports.getPlayer = (req, res, next) => {
    TeamModel.findOne({ _id: req.params.id }, (err, result) => {
        res.render('playerDetails', {
            title: 'Player Detail',
            playerDetails: result,
            playerId: req.params.playerId
        })
    });
};
```

My ejs template:

```
<tbody>
        <!-- since both the _id are objects their memory address are unique, I had to convert it to string to compare-->
        <% for(let i= 0; i < playerDetails.players.length; i++) {%>
        <%if(JSON.stringify(playerDetails.players[i]._id) === JSON.stringify(playerId)){%>
        <tr>
            <td><%=playerDetails.players[i].playerName%></td>
            <td><%=playerDetails.players[i].age%></td>
            <td><%=playerDetails.players[i].jerseyNum%></td>
        </tr>
        <% } %>
        <% } %>
    </tbody>
```

So what I did was I passed in a separate key called `playerId` in my `getPlayer` controller function which will be received in the `playerDetails.ejs`. I passed that so that I could check for the exact id that would match to a single player.

Main thing I was not doing well was to convert the objects into string. As objects have different memory addresses, it will never equal each other, therefore, not showing anything on the page. 
That's why I use `JSON.stringify()` to convert `._id` to a string.